# Fade in/out endless loop

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a selfmade "gallery" with previous and next arrows. Now I wanted to make the arrows fadein on an onmouseover event but I get an endless fadein/out loop when I touch the arrow.

```
<div id="stage" style="z-index:50;" onmouseover="shownavigation(1)" onmouseout="shownavigation(2)">
    <img id ="stageimg" name="phpimg" src="uploads/phpimg.png" onload="vertAlign(this)"/>
    <div id="navright" style="z-index: 2; overflow: hidden; display:none; position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 100px; width: 15px; height: 100px; text-align: center;"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="navigate('r')"><img src="images/red-pfeil.png" alt="" width="17" height="100" align="texttop" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function shownavigation(inout) {
    if(inout==1) {
        $("#navright").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $("#navright").fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Maybe you have an idea.

Comment: Are you able to paste your whole code? I can't even get navright to show up based on what has been provided.

Comment: Created a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/XV9D7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do ***NOT*** use inline JavaScript code. Attch events with jQuery instead. Here's a solution:

```
<div id="stage" style="z-index:50;">
    <img id ="stageimg" name="phpimg" src="uploads/phpimg.png" onload="vertAlign(this)"/>
    <div id="navright" style="z-index: 2; overflow: hidden; display:none; position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 100px; width: 15px; height: 100px; text-align: center;"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="navigate('r')"><img src="images/red-pfeil.png" alt="" width="17" height="100" align="texttop" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#stage").hover(function(){
        $("#navright").stop().fadeIn("slow"); 
    }, function(){
        $("#navright").stop().fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: @Nenad `.fadeIn()` shows the element, you don't have to call it twice.

Comment: No, no, oposite. Hide, then fadeIn (show), to see all animation. Transitions look more stable when you hover-unhover rapidly. No need for "slow".

Comment: @Nenad If you feel like this answer can be improved, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

i think moving the `div#navright` out of your main div should work, like:

```
<div id="stage" style="z-index:50;" onmouseover="shownavigation(1)" onmouseout="shownavigation(2)">

<img id ="stageimg" name="phpimg" src="uploads/phpimg.png" onload="vertAlign(this)"/>

</div>
//move it out
<div id="navright" style="z-index: 2; overflow: hidden; display:none; position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 100px; width: 15px; height: 100px; text-align: center;">     
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="navigate('r')">
     <img src="images/red-pfeil.png" alt="" width="17" height="100" align="texttop" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing its better to use the following code to attach the events.

```
$("#div").hover(function(){
    $("#div").fadeIn("slow");
}, function(){
    $("#div").fadeOut();
});
```

Try to call `stopPropagation()` on the events.

We can also use alternative event that stops propagation by default like, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` or `hover` (out or over).